# Как написать свою процедуру удаления файла на PascalABC.net?

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Задача:

> Написать процедуру `Erase` самому. (процедуру удаление файла)

Как это сделать?

Comment: Уточните, о каком именно языке программирования речь, и удаление файла откуда и в какой операционной системе?

Comment: PascalABC.net -Удаление к примеру самого обычного TXT файла, но процедуру я должен написать сам с нуля, операционная система Windows.

Comment: Насколько низкий уровень вам нужен? Достаточно ли провести стандартные проверки и обратиться к функции DeleteFile WIndows API, а затем обработать результат? Если да, то смотрите https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-deletefilew

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
procedure Erase(Path: string);
begin
  if System.IO.File.Exists(Path) then
    System.IO.File.Delete(Path) 
  else 
    System.Console.WriteLine('File does not exist');
end;

begin 
  Erase('C:\ы.txt');
end.
```